# Sending HEX code to the projector via rs232

Tags: python, serial-port

I want to control projection via rs232. Need will sent code 7E 30 30 30 30 20 31 0D. But i cant correctly write code in python. I find this solution but its give me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\12.py", line 35, in <module>
    ser.write(cmd.decode('hex')+'\r\n')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Odd-length string
```

Code:

```
import serial
import time

port = "COM1"
ser = serial.Serial(port,9600,timeout=0.5)
print(ser.name + ' is open.')

def bits_to_hex(user64bit): # convert the 8-bit user input to hex
    numInt = int(user64bit, 2)
    strHex = hex(numInt)
    userHex = strHex[2:].zfill(2)
    # make sure the payload is a two-digit hex
    return userHex


while True:
    input = raw_input("Enter HEX cmd or 'exit'>> ")
    if input == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        print(port+' is closed.')
        exit()

    elif len(input) == 64:
    # user enters new register value, convert it into hex
        newRegisterValue = bits_to_hex(input)
        ser.write(newRegisterValue.decode('hex')+'\r\n')
        print('Saving...'+newRegisterValue)
        print('Receiving...')
        out = ser.read(1)
        for byte in out:
            print(byte) # present ascii

    else:
        cmd = input
        print('Sending...'+cmd)
        ser.write(cmd.decode('hex')+'\r\n')
        print('Receiving...')
        out = ser.read(1)
        for byte in out:
            print(byte) # present ascii
```

Comment: What exactly is your input?

Comment: I am new in python programming and hex code. This I was find in google and transform to my needs. I dont under stand how corretly sent code to projection in format "7E 30 30 30 30 20 31 0D"

Comment: Basically what you need to send in Python is:`'\x7e\x30\x30\x30\x30\x20\x31\x0d'` which actually is `'~0000 1\r'`. As you can see the `\r` is already included.

Comment: i wrote such code, but i dont understand.  import serial
import time
import binascii
port = "COM1"
ser = serial.Serial(port,9600,timeout=0.5)
print(ser.name + ' is open.')
input = raw_input("Enter HEX cmd or 'exit'>> ")
print(input)

list_ascii=[ord(i) for i in input]

list_hex=[hex(k) for k in list_ascii]


print (list_ascii)
print (list_hex)



ser.write(serial.to_bytes(list_hex))

Comment: Like this your code is not readable. Add all code to your question!